# SSH config file - Multipule users for the same host group

Tags: linux, ssh

Currently I have the following ssh config file:

```
Host 172.30.*
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/cm_socket/%r@%h:%p

  ServerAliveInterval    60
  TCPKeepAlive           yes
  ProxyCommand           ssh -i /home/ehud/.ssh/my-secret1.pem -q -A ubuntu@some.public.ip nc %h %p
  ControlMaster          auto
  ControlPath            ~/.ssh/mux-%r@%h:%p
  ControlPersist         8h
  User                   ubuntu
  IdentityFile           /home/ehud/.ssh/my-secret1.pem
```

Now I have other machines in the same subnet (172.30.*) but they have a different secret pem file. I would like to add same configuration with a different secret pem file and call ssh with some flag that will redirect me to the right secret file.

Is it possible??

Thanks

Comment: The title says `multiple users` as if you wanted to do something with the `User` parameter; but the body of your question suggests it's about `IdentityFile`. I hope I got you right and my answer is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ssh -i '/home/ehud/.ssh/my-secret2.pem' …
ssh -o 'IdentityFile=/home/ehud/.ssh/my-secret2.pem' …
```

Either of the above commands will load `my-secret2.pem` file first, but since you can specify multiple identity files (see [`man 1 ssh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh), `-i` option), the file `my-secret1.pem` given in your `ssh_config` will possibly also be tried. You may or may not want this.

If you're OK with this then you can specify `my-secret2.pem` via `ssh_config` by adding the following snippet *before* the `Host 172.30.*` block you already have:

```
# Special hosts, new identity file.
Host 172.30.10.*
  IdentityFile           /home/ehud/.ssh/my-secret2.pem
```

[`man 5 ssh_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) says:

> For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used. The configuration files contain sections separated by `Host` specifications, and that section is only applied for hosts that match one of the patterns given in the specification. The matched host name is the one given on the command line.
>
> Since the first obtained value for each parameter is used, more host-specific declarations should be given near the beginning of the file, and general defaults at the end.

For any parameter that can be specified only once, it would be enough to match special hosts first, the whole `172.30.*` range later. It's not obvious but "the first obtained value will be used" doesn't really apply to `IdentityFile` because you can specify multiple files. To make your special hosts *not* use the `my-secret1.pem` file, you need additional knowledge of an exclamation mark (`!`) usage.

Example snippet of `ssh_config`:

```
# Special hosts, new identity file.
Host 172.30.10.*
  IdentityFile           /home/ehud/.ssh/my-secret2.pem

# Non-special hosts, old identity file.
Host 172.30.* !172.30.10.*
  IdentityFile           /home/ehud/.ssh/my-secret1.pem

# Special and non-special hosts, like in your old config.
# Note there is no IdentityFile line here anymore.
# If there was, it would apply to special and non-special
# hosts, despite some previous IdentityFile line alrady loaded.
Host 172.30.*
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/cm_socket/%r@%h:%p

  ServerAliveInterval    60
  TCPKeepAlive           yes
  ProxyCommand           ssh -i /home/ehud/.ssh/my-secret1.pem -q -A ubuntu@some.public.ip nc %h %p
  ControlMaster          auto
  ControlPath            ~/.ssh/mux-%r@%h:%p
  ControlPersist         8h
  User                   ubuntu
```

Now if you e.g. `ssh -v 172.30.10.22` (special host), you will see something like:

```
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line X: Applying options for 172.30.10.*
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line Y: Skipping Host block because of negated match for 172.30.10.*
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line Z: Applying options for 172.30.*
```

and `ssh -v 172.30.99.33` (non-special host) will print:

```
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line Y: Applying options for 172.30.*
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line Z: Applying options for 172.30.*
```

So either way only one `.pem` file will be used.

There is also `-F` option for `ssh`. From [`man 1 ssh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh):

> `-F configfile`
> Specifies an alternative per-user configuration file. If a configuration file is given on the command line, the system-wide configuration file (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`) will be ignored. The default for the per-user configuration file is `~/.ssh/config`.

This way you can load a completely different config by hand.